# hide some part of the url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following htaccess file which works for my application:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

How to change urls like http://example.com/de/contact to
http://example.com/contact ?

I tried something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^de/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ de/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Change `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ de/$1 [L]` to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /de/$1 [L]`

Comment: Ok I can access http://example.com/contact now. But the server returns a 404 error for all the /css/ and /js/ files for the template.

Comment: Use a `<base>` tag to resolve that: https://devdocs.io/html/element/base

Comment: But the base path is ok. The path to the css files is not wrong.